# Compiling CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp and CMakeCCompilerId.c files failed error in CMakeLists.txt file while configuring OpenCV with CMake

Tags: java, cmake, tbb, opencv3.0

I am doing object detection in images using [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) library in Eclipse java. For this I need to create a `.vec` file using [`opencv_createsamples`](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html) utility in command prompt but `opencv_createsamples` is not getting recognized in Dos prompt.

So I need to configure opencv enabled with TBB with CMake but getting compilation error in `CMakeCCompilerId.c` and `CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp` files in CMakeLists.txt file.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This error message normally just means that `CMake` was unable to compile a simple test program (one of the first things `CMake` tries while detecting your build environment). Could you please add the complete error message to your question (because the reason for the error is most likely also in the message) and please add the command line `CMake` call you are trying also? General speaking you probably don't have the compiler environment set (see e.g. [Why does Cmake Always Choose GCC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856952/why-does-cmake-always-choose-gcc)).

Comment: Thanks Florian. To resolve this error I downloaded these two files and copied them in source folder of opencv.

Comment: But now I am getting another error. The CXX compiler identification is unknown
The C compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:88 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:88 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Comment: If we are talking about `CMakeCCompilerId.c` and `CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp`, those are generated by CMake to test/find the compiler. So no need to download them. Your error message says, `CMake` can't find your C/CXX compiler. What OS and compiler toolchain are you targeting? Does your compiler work outside CMake if called directly? If e.g. `Linux` and `GNU` what does happen if you call `gcc` in a `bash` shell? I get `gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files` `compilation terminated.`, which is good because it did find `gcc` and it's complaining that I didn't gave it any parameters to work with.

Comment: And please take a look at `CMakeError.log`. There you will find what CMake tried to call.

Comment: Duplicate to [How to use OpenCv utilities in Command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623586/how-to-use-opencv-utilities-in-command-prompt)

Comment: After 4 years. I am having the same issue. the error message `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` could not be found` means that it `gcc/g++ `compiler could not be found. You need to set it as `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++.exe`