# How to use OpenCv utilities in Command prompt

Tags: java, cmake, tbb, opencv3.0

I am doing object detection in images using `OpenCv` library in Java Eclipse. I am using Cascade Classifier Training for this using `Haar` features.

For training the classifier I need to generate some text files, `.vec` file and finally `.xml` file on command prompt. I have already generated text files but while making `.vec` file using `opencv_createsamples` utility on command prompt, I am getting error:

> opencv_createsamples command is not recognized.

To resolve this I need to build `opencv` with `TBB` Threading Building using `CMake`. I am unable to do this. Please anyone suggest me the full and proper method of building `opencv` with `TBB` using `Cmake`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That blog describes building OpenCV with TBB enabled(`WITH_TBB=ON`) on Ubuntu 14.04: http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/10/installing-opencv-3-0-0-on-ubuntu-14-04/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the right file name by doing a search in explorer. then add the address prefix. Notice that this example has a d for debug.

C:\opencv\bin\Debug\opencv_createsamplesd.exe -vec samples.vec